# SonarQube is not displaying PMD violations

Tags: sonarqube

I have configured PMD plugin in pom xml of my project and ran

```
pmd:check
```

This resulted in pmd.xml generated with violations in my target folder.

Now, I have ran

```
sonar:sonar
```

to perform the code analysis on sonarQube. But, I cannot find the violations generated in the **sonarQube**.

**Note:**

I have configured custom quality profile and have selected generated xml.

Even then the code violations are not shown in sonarqube?

Could anyone tell what I am missing here?

Comment: it is hard to tell you without any specifics. Please provide some configuration, eg. how did you configure the path to the pmd.xml - do you use the pmd plugin for sonarqube, or do you rely on the generic issue format? What does the log of the scanner tell us regarding pmd or report analysing.

Comment: I got the resolution. It was because I didn't mention the PMD  xml report path while running the sonar analysis. Thankyou